How to get label address on GNU Assembler
This must be something really stupid; I'm trying to get the address for a label and store it into a .word on GNU Assembler, but for some weird reason, it's not working as I expect it to work.
Take the following code:
data:   .word data_r
data_r: .byte 0x65

main: j main

My understanding is that data should contain the address for data_r (00000004, for instance?), but it seems like it's just 0x00000000.
> riscv64-unknown-elf-as  -march=rv32ec -mabi=ilp32e -o test.o test.s && riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -dsS test.o 

test.o:     file format elf32-littleriscv


Contents of section .text:
 0000 00000000 6501a000                    ....e...        
Contents of section .riscv.attributes:
 0000 411e0000 00726973 63760001 14000000  A....riscv......
 0010 05727633 32653170 395f6332 703000    .rv32e1p9_c2p0. 

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <data>:
   0:   00000000                .word   0x00000000

00000004 <data_r>:
   4:   65                      .byte   0x65

00000005 <main>:
   5:   a001                    j       5 <main>

What I'm trying to achieve is basically a list, data would contain multiple addresses, so I think this should be pretty straightforward.
Can somebody help me understand what is it that I'm missing here?

The address will be filled in by the linker. The assembler just put an offset and a relocation entry there. See also objdump -dr.

@Jester that's an interesting tip! I'm not using a linker, but just riscv64-unknown-elf-as then riscv64-unknown-elf-objcopy to get the bare metal binary. Should I find a way of chaining a linker in there, for example? I don't know if I can disassemble the output of objcopy, but that one also seems to be broken.

Yes, you should probably use a linker instead of objcopy.

@Jester Thank you, it seems this is what I needed to know. Can you add this as an answer? I think it working now with the linker.
